# Argument #2 is not an array in OpenCart template

Tags: php, opencart

I am facing following error will you please tell me about the solution:

> (Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/faqirhus/public_html/---/catalog/view/theme/pav_metro/template/product/product.tpl on line 13

Here is my code:

```
    <?php require( DIR_TEMPLATE.$this->config->get('config_template')."/template/common/config.tpl" ); 
  $themeConfig = $this->config->get('themecontrol');
  $productConfig = array(
      'product_enablezoom'=>1,
      'product_zoommode'  => 'basic',
      'product_zoomeasing' => 1,
      'product_zoomlensshape' => "round",
      'product_zoomlenssize' => "150",
      'product_zoomgallery'  => 0,
      'extra_images_visiable' => 3,
      'product_related_column'=>'', 
  );
  $productConfig = array_merge( $productConfig, $themeConfig );

  $categoryPzoom = isset($themeConfig['category_pzoom']) ? $themeConfig['category_pzoom']:0;   

?>


<?php echo $header; ?>

<div class="product-view">

    <?php if( $SPAN[0] ): ?>
    <div class="span<?php echo $SPAN[0];?>">
        <?php echo $column_left; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?> 

    <div class="span<?php echo $SPAN[1];?>">

        <div id="content">
            <?php echo $content_top; ?>

            <div class="breadcrumb">
                <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
                <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>  


            <div class="product-info">
                <div class="pav-view-top">
                    <div class="row-fluid">

                <?php if ($thumb || $images) { ?>
                <div class="span5 product-img-box">

                    <!-- Lable Special Product -->
                    <?php if( $special )  { ?>
                        <span class="product-label-special label"><?php echo $this->language->get( 'text_sale' ); ?></span>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <!-- Image -->
                    <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
                    <div class="image">
                        <a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox">
                            <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image"  data-zoom-image="<?php echo $popup; ?>" class="product-image-zoom"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ($images) { ?>
                    <div class="image-additional slide carousel" id="image-additional">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <?php 
                        if( $productConfig['product_zoomgallery'] == 'slider' && $thumb ) {  
                            $eimages = array( 0=> array( 'popup'=>$popup,'thumb'=> $popup )  ); 
                            $images = array_merge( $eimages, $images );
                        }

                        $icols = 3; $i= 0;
                        foreach ($images as  $image) { ?>
                        <?php if( (++$i)%$icols == 1 ) { ?>
                        <div class="item">
                        <?php } ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox" data-zoom-image="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" data-image="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" style="max-width:<?php echo $this->config->get('config_image_additional_width');?>px"  title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" class="product-image-zoom" />
                        </a>
                        <?php if( $i%$icols == 0 || $i==count($images) ) { ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>                      
                        </div>                      

                        <div class="carousel-control left" href="#image-additional" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</div>
                        <div class="carousel-control right" href="#image-additional" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</div>
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $('#image-additional .item:first').addClass('active');
                        $('#image-additional').carousel({interval:false})
                    </script>
                    <?php } ?>

                </div>
                <?php } ?>                              

                <div class="span7">
                    <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>                          
                        <div class="pav-view-content">                      
                            <?php if ($review_status) { ?>
                                <div class="review">
                                    <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/pav_metro/image/stars-<?php echo $rating; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $reviews; ?>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="$('a[href=\'#tab-review\']').trigger('click');"><?php echo $reviews; ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="$('a[href=\'#tab-review\']').trigger('click');"><?php echo $text_write; ?></a></div>
                                    <div class="share clearfix">
                                        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                                        <div class="addthis_default_style"><a class="addthis_button_compact"><?php echo $text_share; ?></a> <a class="addthis_button_email"></a><a class="addthis_button_print"></a> <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a> <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a></div>
                                        <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></script> 
                                        <!-- AddThis Button END --> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <div class="description">
                                <?php if ($manufacturer) { ?>
                                    <span><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?></span><a href="<?php echo $manufacturers; ?>"> <?php echo $manufacturer; ?></a><br />
                                <?php } ?>
                                    <span><?php echo $text_model; ?></span> <?php echo $model; ?><br />
                                <?php if ($reward) { ?>
                                    <span><?php echo $text_reward; ?></span> <?php echo $reward; ?><br />
                                <?php } ?>
                                    <span><?php echo $text_stock; ?></span> <?php echo $stock; ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="pav-product-detail">
                                <div class="row-fluid">   
                                <?php if ($price) { ?>
                                <div class="span6">
                                    <div class="price">
                                        <?php echo $text_price; ?>
                                        <?php if (!$special) { ?>
                                        <?php echo $price; ?>
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                        <span class="price-old"><?php echo $price; ?></span> 
                                        <span class="price-new"><?php echo $special; ?></span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <br />
                                        <?php if ($tax) { ?>
                                        <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $tax; ?></span><br />
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <?php if ($points) { ?>
                                        <span class="reward"><small><?php echo $text_points; ?> <?php echo $points; ?></small></span><br />
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <?php if ($discounts) { ?>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="discount">
                                        <?php foreach ($discounts as $discount) { ?>
                                        <?php echo sprintf($text_discount, $discount['quantity'], $discount['price']); ?><br />
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>    
                                <?php } ?>  


                                <?php if ($profiles): ?>
                                  <div class="option">
                                      <h2><span class="required">*</span><?php echo $text_payment_profile ?></h2>
                                      <br />
                                      <select name="profile_id">
                                          <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
                                          <?php foreach ($profiles as $profile): ?>
                                          <option value="<?php echo $profile['profile_id'] ?>"><?php echo $profile['name'] ?></option>
                                          <?php endforeach; ?>
                                      </select>
                                      <br />
                                      <br />
                                      <span id="profile-description"></span>
                                      <br />
                                      <br />
                                  </div>
                                  <?php endif; ?>   




                                <?php if ($options) { ?>
                                <div class="options">
                                    <h2><?php echo $text_option; ?></h2>

                                    <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
                                    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
                                    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
                                        <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
                                        <span class="required">*</span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
                                        <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" class="span12">
                                            <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
                                            <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
                                            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                                            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            </option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>           
                                    <br />
                                    <?php } ?>

                                    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'radio') { ?>
                                    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
                                        <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
                                            <span class="required">*</span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />

                                        <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
                                        <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
                                        <label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
                                            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                                            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </label>
                                        <br />
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <?php } ?>          

                                    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'checkbox') { ?>
                                    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
                                        <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
                                        <span class="required">*</span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
                                        <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
                                        <label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
                                            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                                            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </label>
                                        <br />
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>          
                                    <br />
                                    <?php } ?>


                                    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'image') { ?>
                                    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
                                    <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
                                        <span class="required">*</span>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
                                    <table class="option-image">
                                        <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 1px;">
                                                <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $option_value['name'] . ($option_value['price'] ? ' ' . $option_value['price_prefix'] . $option_value['price'] : ''); ?>" /></label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
                                                <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                                                (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
                                                <?php } ?>
                                                </label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <?php } ?>


                                    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'text') { ?>
                                    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
                                        <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
                                            <span class="required">*</span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
                                        <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" class="span12" />
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <?php } ?>


                                    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'textarea') { ?>
                                    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
                                        <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
                                            <span class="required">*</span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
                                        <textarea name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" cols="40" rows="5" class="span12"><?php echo $option['option_value']; ?></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <?php } ?>          


                                    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { ?>
                                    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
                                        <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
                                            <span class="required">*</span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
                                        <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_upload; ?>" id="button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="button">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <?php } ?>          

                                    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'date') { ?>
                                    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
                                        <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
                                            <span class="required">*</span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
                                        <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" class="date span12" />
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <?php } ?>          


                                    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'datetime') { ?>
                                    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
                                        <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
                                            <span class="required">*</span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
                                        <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" class="datetime span12" />
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <?php } ?>


                                    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'time') { ?>
                                    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
                                        <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
                                            <span class="required">*</span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
                                        <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" class="time span12" />
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <?php } ?>          

                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div>    
                                <?php } ?>
                                </div>

                                <div class="span6">
                                    <div class="cart">
                                        <div class="pav-add-to-cart clearfix">
                                            <div class="pav-qty pull-left">
                                                <span><?php echo $text_qty; ?></span>
                                                <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
                                            </div>                      
                                            <div class="pav-cart pull-right">
                                                <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" id="button-cart" class="button" />
                                            </div>                      
                                            <?php /* <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $text_or; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> */ ?>     
                                        </div>
                                        <?php if ($minimum > 1) { ?>
                                            <p class="minimum"><?php echo $text_minimum; ?></p>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: It seems quite obvious, `$themeConfig` is not an array. Check what `$this->config->get('themecontrol')` is returning!!!

Answer (score -2):

$themeConfig must be an array 
be sure that this line return an array

```
 $themeConfig = $this->config->get('themecontrol');
```